# Shell.Current.GoToAsync is not working on UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp

I want to use Xamarin.Forms Shell on the UWP platform, so I downloaded the example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/, and then i updated all the nugets, so the version of xamarin forms is 4.7.0.1179. When i built this project and run it "Shell.Current.GoToAsync" has no effect on the UWP platform.

[image]

My development environment:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I want to know if this is normal, if not how can i fix this?

Comment: Hi, is it UWP? It works on Android.

Comment: Hi, I tried it again, but it did not work. Do you think it has something to do with my development environment?

Comment: Please share your os version  visual studio version and the app's target version

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218511/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-zhichaoxiang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Shell.Current.GoToAsync is not working on UWP

It's know issue in UWP platform, and it was fix in pre-release version. Please try to update the Xamarin.Form nugget to [4.8.0.1187-pre2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/4.8/4.8.0-pre2) will fix this issue.